# MySQL: A help needed in Query using 4 tables

Tags: mysql

There are these four tables:

```
posts
posts_replies
likes
myfavorite
```

I am using the following query to return me data from first 3 tables. But the 4th table (myfavorite), i want it to be also included into it and load the post that user has selected as Favorite.

```
SELECT  posts.title, 
    posts.num, 
    posts.status, 
    posts.category, 
    posts.content, 
    posts.member_num, 
    COUNT( posts_replies.post_num ) AS count, 
    COUNT( likes.comment_num ) AS likes_count
FROM    posts
    LEFT JOIN posts_replies 
        ON ( posts_replies.post_num = posts.num )
    LEFT JOIN likes 
        ON ( likes.comment_num = posts_replies.num )
WHERE   posts.member_num = '84'
GROUP   BY posts.num 
ORDER   BY posts.num
```

myfavorite table has following fields:

```
id (primary key)
member_num 
recordNum 
table ('posts' OR 'members')
```

I tried adding the following left join into the above query to pull the records from myfavorite table too, but its not working:

```
LEFT JOIN myfavorite 
ON ( myfavorite.recordNum = posts.num )
```

I am confused with this query, any advices on this?

Thank you

EDIT **

Here are the tables with sample data from `posts` and `myfavorite` tables:

table: `myfavorite`

```
id  |   member_num  |   recordNum   |   table   
72  |   84          |   74          |   blyrbs
```

table: `posts`

```
title       |   num |   status  |   category    |   content                 |   member_num
Testing Post|   117 |       1   |   0           |   testing...              |   84
My Fav Post |   107 |       1   |   0           |   this is the fav post... |   22
```

Comment: You need to find a field that myfavorite has in common with another one of the 3 tables and join on that field. Is there such a field?

Comment: @Melanie yes there is, in `myfavorite` table, its `recordNum`, which is common to `posts`.`num`

Comment: In that case, what do you mean by "it's not working"? What happens when you add that JOIN to your query?

Comment: it doesn't the pull the record from the `myfavorite` table.

Comment: there are two records: 1 in `posts` table and one in `myfavorite` table (which is a reference to a post that member marked as favorite). When add a `LEFT JOIN myfavorite ON ( myfavorite.recordNum = posts.num )` into the query, only 1 record from `posts` table is fetched and not from the `myfavorite` table. The result should show 2 records.

Comment: I think you're mixing your concepts here. On one hand you're doing 'group by' operations and on the other your trying to select a single record. This smells like two queries to me.

Comment: But if there's one record in posts and one in myfavorite, you should only get one row, with the columns you specify in your select statement. It sounds to me like your query is working.

Comment: i have added sample table data for your review, plz check.

Comment: Did you add the columns that you want to fetch in the select query?

Comment: just edited my question again and added little formatting for better view and one more row which is a post that is marked as fav by member.

Comment: my basic objective is to pull records from posts table using `member_num` in `posts` table as well as in `myfavorites` table.

Comment: I thought so.  the join with `member_num` column in both tables  instead of `recordNum` and `num`.  `LEFT JOIN myfavorite 
ON ( myfavorite.member_num = posts.member_num )`

Comment: @slowcoder can build a query using the above tables as per my scope?

Comment: i have also tried `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` on `myfavorite` table, but still the result remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i myself found my answer, i was actually using this part of the query wrong:

```
LEFT JOIN myfavorite 
    ON ( myfavorite.member_num = posts.member_num )
```

Where it should be this:

```
    LEFT JOIN myfavorite 
        ON ( myfavorite.recordNum = posts.num )
```

And also i changed the following `WHERE` clause:
Original was only:

```
WHERE   posts.member_num = 84
```

And the edited one working is:

```
WHERE   posts.member_num = 84 OR myfavorite.member_num = 84
```

So the final working query is this: **`(Query took 0.2901 sec)`**

```
SELECT  posts.title, 
    posts.num, 
    posts.status, 
    posts.category, 
    posts.content, 
    posts.member_num, 
    myfavorite.recordNum,
    myfavorite.`table`,
    COUNT( posts_replies.post_num ) AS count, 
    COUNT( likes.comment_num ) AS likes_count
FROM    posts
    LEFT JOIN posts_replies 
        ON ( posts_replies.post_num = posts.num )
    LEFT JOIN likes 
        ON ( likes.comment_num = posts_replies.num )
    LEFT JOIN myfavorite 
        ON ( myfavorite.recordNum = posts.num )
WHERE   posts.member_num = 84 OR myfavorite.member_num = 84
GROUP   BY posts.num 
ORDER   BY posts.num
```

It is giving pulling two records exactly as wanted.

But there is a new problem that i am seeing, its the time that the query is taking. I think the above query is not efficient.

If i change back the where clause to **`WHERE   posts.member_num = 84`** then the query only takes **`0.0059 sec`**

I want to know if this is really the best and efficient way?

Btw, thank you @Slowcoder, @Melanie and @ethrbunny for your time and advices.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the query to get the results you expect?  I am confused about the relationship between these two tables (`posts` and `myfavourite`).  Do you have any foreign key constraints defined?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following query?

```
SELECT  posts.title, 
    posts.num, 
    posts.status, 
    posts.category, 
    posts.content, 
    posts.member_num, 
    myfavourite.record_num,
    myfavourite.table,
    COUNT( posts_replies.post_num ) AS count, 
    COUNT( likes.comment_num ) AS likes_count
FROM    posts
    LEFT JOIN posts_replies 
        ON ( posts_replies.post_num = posts.num )
    LEFT JOIN likes 
        ON ( likes.comment_num = posts_replies.num )
    LEFT JOIN myfavorite 
        ON ( myfavorite.member_num = posts.member_num )
WHERE   posts.member_num = 84
GROUP   BY posts.num 
ORDER   BY posts.num
```

Comment: I tried it but its still showing the same single record with the title `Testing Post`.